# Does alias could work within $row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SUM function to get the total of the sales row but the thing is, it was also belongs to an INNER JOIN.

Will this work properly? I mean is `SUM(b.sales)` is an acceptable query?

See the codes below:

> $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT a.startDate, SUM (b.sales) FROM sales b 
>      INNER JOIN inventory a ON a.startDate = b.date");
>
> ```
>   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
>   {
>       $rrr=$row['sum(b.sales)'];
>       echo formatMoney($rrr, true);
>   }
> ```

Okay. Now I've tried it but it isn't working.

This is what I'm trying to do:

[link](https://scontent-a-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/q71/s720x720/10450979_884758901539713_1728450556334349461_n.jpg)

Comment: did you try it? what happened?

Comment: `SELECT ..., SUM (b.sales) AS TotalSales...` and on PHP, `$row['TotalSales'];`

Comment: @JakeGould sorry, I forgot to include the word tried. But I did it, and seems not working. Again pardon me for not being exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare new name on `SUM (b.sales) as sumSales` as code below

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT a.startDate, SUM (b.sales) as sumSales FROM sales b INNER JOIN inventory a ON a.startDate = b.date");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $rrr=$row['sumSales'];
    echo formatMoney($rrr, true);
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but still nothing happens. The total amount isn't displaying. I've tried to change my query but after so many unsuccessful attempts, still this issue couldn't be resolved. :(

please see the link for you to see how's the output look like, I can't post the image here.

[link](https://scontent-a-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/q71/s720x720/10450979_884758901539713_1728450556334349461_n.jpg)

Comment: please add `group by b.date` to calculate daily sales as [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4699/3)

Comment: just a follow-up question.

Here's the whole picture of the system's output:

[link](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/q72/s720x720/10495352_884821198200150_5471997974521134169_o.jpg)

The column for no. of rented property is connected to the rent cost. The product of these 2 columns will be the value for the Amount Tendered column. I decided to use Live_table_edit function for the No. Of rented property column to achieve the fb-comment-like theme for this. So whenever the user clicks any cell from the No. of Rented Property column, ....

Comment: a hidden textfield (not really hidden, just appears to be) will be shown for the user to fill data. then ofcourse, whatever the user fills with it, would be multiplied with the rent cost column and the amount tendered can now be shown.

But the thing is, I'm having some difficulty with live_edit_table function so perhaps that is the reason why until now some of the details particularly the no.of rented property and amount tendered isn't showing

Comment: please post a new question with a new title

Comment: thus the total still didn't add the other inserted data. (It was stuck at 10,000. Though in reality it must now be on 20k since I've been doing a lot of trial.)

And per every row, there must be a sub-total. for example, userA gives a downpayment for this day, and another one tomorrow, the sub-total must appear per each day's payment. And another total for the whole month count.
And so the same with userB, C etc...

Any suggestion?
Sorry I need to cut my comments in 3, coz it won't allow many characters.

Comment: Please see my post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260626/live-edit-issues

Answer (score 4):

The normal pattern is to assign an alias to the expression in the query

```
SELECT SUM(t.foo) AS tot_foo ...
```

and reference the column in the result set by the assigned alias...

```
$totfoo = $row('tot_foo');
```

---

Even if I could get it to "work" without assigning an alias to the expression; even if I could reference the column using the expression, I don't ever want my code looking like this:

```
$totfoo = $row('SUM(t.foo)');
```

That just looks wrong to me; and that's just a simple one. I've got some expressions that would be downright scary as column names in a resultset.

If an alias isn't assigned, some databases will generate a name for the column in the resultset.

I'd much rather reference the column by the name I explicitly specified.